# User authentication for web services in Java

Tags: java, web-services, security, authentication, tomcat

Suppose I have a simple Java server application, which implements a few web (`REST`) services. The application is deployed as `war` in `Tomcat`. Now I would like to add user authentication as follows:

- Add a plain text file `users` with user names and passwords on the server side. User is required to send both user name and password with each request and the server tests them against the file.
- In order to prevent sending passwords as clear text I am considering one-way encryption just like one used in `/etc/passwd`. So users will be required to encrypt their passwords before sending them in the requests.

Does this approach make any sense? Is there any "ready-to-use" implementation of this approach in Java?

Answer (score 3):

[Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/tutorial.html)? This a non-intrusive way of securing web apps and very flexible in how the data can be stored - i.e. a plain text file, xml or a database of usernames and passwords.

Answer (score 1):

There are a ton of ways to skin this cat.  First, you probably want to use digest authentication or SSL form-based authentication, since relying on a client-side hash can be subjected to replay attacks.

My recommendation would be to use Spring Security. Take a look at [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/basic.html) example of HTTP digest authentication.

Another way might be to use the servlet container to accomplish this for you.  Take a look [here](http://java.boot.by/wcd-guide/ch05s03.html) for both digest and form-based auth techniques.

Also, **you should really read up on [proper password storage](http://blankfield.net/better-password-storage/) techniques for web applications**.  Make sure you're using a sufficiently complex (aka slow) hashing algorithm like bcrypt and give each password a unique salt.  Finally, make sure the transport of credentials is secure, either by using HTTP digest authentication (alright), or by using SSL form-based authentication (better).

Answer (score 1):

Use a RESTful framework like [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net) for example. But for authentication you must implement session management with request filters. As for users management you should use a database like MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a lot of existing good authentication solutions, from BASIC (via SSL), OAuth, Kerberos, Spring Security etc. I suggest making a research on WS-Security topic, as there are many layers (container, filters, application itself) where the authentication can take place.